# Insert reference into vector with same lifetime as vector

Tags: rust, reference, lifetime

```
fn test(tokens: &mut Vec<&str>, index: usize) {

    if tokens[index] == "END" {

        let default_token = String::from("DEFAULT");

        tokens.insert(index, &default_token);
    }
}
```

I am inserting default tokens into a token stream (vector of tokens). For efficiency and architectural reasons, the vector is storing a reference to the tokens. Default tokens need to be inserted into the token stream. As the vector is a vector of references, I need a way to create owned data in the function then insert a reference to that data into the vector.

Running the code will give an error stating that the variable 'default_token' is dropped while borrowed.

This is expected as it is popped off the stack at the end of the function call.

Is there a way to bind the lifetime of the variable to the lifetime of the vector so you can insert a reference to the variable into the vector?

I have attempted to try Box the value but I receive the same error as I cannot specify the lifetime of the Box

I can always pass the default tokens as arguments so i can explicity specify the lifetime in relation to eachother. However, I would like to know if i can achieve what i described without having to resort to this alternate approach.

Comment: The strings you are creating live as long as the call to the function, `test`. The vector `tokens` lives **_longer_** than the call to the function. It is not allowed for this vector to contain references to those strings.

Comment: @PeterHall I understand that which is why I specified that while asking my question 'This is expected as it is popped off the stack at the end of the function call'.

Comment: "*I would like [an] alternate approach"* - if your real code uses a string literal (as in `"DEFAULT"`) as the default value, you can insert that directly into the `Vec` since literals have a `'static` lifetime: `tokens.insert(index, "DEFAULT");`

Comment: I think the honest answer to your question is "no, not really". Depending on how you approach it, the "binding the local variable to the vector" you're asking about requires either: 1) a gc-like mechanism, 2) a new language feature that would work non-locally and update all callers recursively, or 3) self-referential data. Since none of these are available, the viable approaches you're left with are: 1) switch the vector to store owned strings or `Cow<str>`, 2) keep tokens in a static var and make them `&'static str`.